# spark filter hbase to get samples

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase

I have a large hbase dataset, and I want to retrieve some data with specific condition to get a sample set to debug with.

Here is the Spark RDD and filter:

```
val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "172.16.1.10,172.16.1.11,172.16.1.12")
conf.setInt("timeout", 120000)
conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, "dateset")
val hbaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, classOf[TableInputFormat], classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable], classOf[Result])
val filteredRDD = rdd.filter{
   case tuple => {
      val result = tuple._2
      val hostId = new String(result.getValue("user", "id"))
      hostId == "12345" // <-- only retrieve the row when user:id is 12345
   }
}
```

Now I get the rdd of `filteredRDD` and I just want to save it back as the same format in another table

```
val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "172.16.1.10,172.16.1.11,172.16.1.12")
conf.setInt("timeout", 120000)
conf.set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, "data_sample")
// here I don't know which api to use
```

Can somebody give me a clue? Thanks.

Comment: I have answered how to do the same in Java below as I am not a Scala expert. Hopefully this exists for Scala as well.

Comment: are you sure your code works for `filteredRDD`? It is not working for me. It says `getValue` method needs `Array[Byte]` instead of string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset** function on pair rdd as follows:

```
JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put> pairs = filterRDD.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Object, ImmutableBytesWritable, Put>() {
    @Override
    public Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put> execute(Object message) throws Exception {

        //prepare the HBase put here
        return new Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put>(new ImmutableBytesWritable(), put);
    }
});

Job newAPIJobConfiguration = Job.getInstance(hbaseConf);
newAPIJobConfiguration.getConfiguration().set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, tableName);
newAPIJobConfiguration.setOutputFormatClass(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat.class);

pairs.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(newAPIJobConfiguration.getConfiguration());
```